# Which data flow transform component is able to separate & extract data by specifying a delimit type such as a comma or a pipe?

Tags: ssis, delimited

IF a table field contains string value delimited by a pipe like:

"John|Lee|12-01-2015"

When SSIS reads it, is there an SSIS component that you can specify a separator and map each into next flow stage?

Say. data flow reads it("John|Lee|12-01-2015") into a variable, then anything can separate the whole string by | and map each sub-value into a set of column via configuration?

I know it is pretty simple to use C# to do it. In SSIS, script component can be used. Just wonder if there is an SSIS component for it, pretty much lile a flat file source, but read from a variable rather than a file.

Comment: Use variable expressions and get this values in each variable :)

Comment: I'd do it in the query in the SQL Data Source.   But no, there's no built-in component that I know of that's made to do something like this.

Comment: You could also do this in a Derived Column task immediately after pulling it out of the database if you didn't want to do it in SQL for some reason. Add a new column for each column you need, and parse the original column value in the expressions.